# Sculpting grab tool causing pointy mesh?

Tags: sculpting

I'm trying to learn some sculpting techniques in Blender and at first I thought that I'm doing something wrong (and probably still am) concerning the grab sculpting brush, because I just couldn't get it to pull in the natural ways. So I watched some online tutorials and without them mentioning any change than what I was doing I saw that my brush was indeed acting strange.

For example [this is one of the videos I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXjG8jEa9SI).
The sculpting starts at around 4:00 minutes in. When he uses the grab tool you can see that the mesh is pulled in the direction he drags and deforms quite nicely, also even the middle parts of the mesh are pulled.

However when I follow his exact same steps (I even made sure of the view settings) grab brush pulls it diagonally in the direction I am pulling, but also pulls it towards the viewer (screen). It is also very pointy.

Note: I used the grab tool here just to illustrate my problem and didn't try to emulate the tutorial again.

Right ortho view of sculpt (same one as tutorial):
[image: Right ortho view of sculpt]

Front view of sculpt:
[image: Front ortho view of sculpt]

As you can see it does not pull the middle part (X mirroring is active), also it seems to pull more on corners than edges, which makes it very pointy. I tried playing around with most of the brush settings, but couldn't find anything that seemed to be improving it.

Comment: try to zoom out more and increase brush radius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a bigger brush radius (<kbd>F</kbd> + drag to change).

Small radius:

[image]

Large radius:

[image]

Also try to drag close to the edge of the object.
When you grab closer to the center (thinking in 2D), you are really grabbing the side of the object, affecting geometry "closer" to the screen more than geometry near the actual center, which is at the edge of the visible portion of the object when in side ortho view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you kind sir! You are indeed a wizard! So he really meant it when he said make the brush quite big. Thanks a lot.